# Sauce Labs with protractor, malformed URI

Tags: node.js, selenium, protractor, saucelabs

My protractor config is:

```
exports.config = {
baseUrl: 'http://www.onet.pl',
directConnect: false,
sauceUser: 'myuser',
sauceKey: 'mypassword',

 capabilities: {
    'browserName': 'chrome',
    'chromeOptions': {
        'args': ['show-fps-counter=true', '--allow-running-insecure-content']
    }
},
}
```

When I try to launch the tests I get the following Error:

> ```
>     [12:57:56] I/sauce - Using SauceLabs selenium server at   http://ondemand.saucelabs.com:80/wd/hub
>  [12:57:56] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
> [12:57:56] E/launcher - URI malformed
> [12:57:56] E/launcher - URIError: URI malformed
>     at decodeURIComponent (native)
>     at Url.parse (url.js:275:19)
>     at Object.urlParse [as parse] (url.js:81:5)
>     at new HttpClient (C:\Users\gwk736\Gitlab\Inform\e2e\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\http\index.js:221:25)
>     at C:\Users\gwk736\Gitlab\Inform\e2e\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\executors.js:47:18
>     at ManagedPromise.invokeCallback_ (C:\Users\gwk736\Gitlab\Inform\e2e\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:1379:14)
>     at TaskQueue.execute_ (C:\Users\gwk736\Gitlab\Inform\e2e\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:2913:14)
>     at TaskQueue.executeNext_ (C:\Users\gwk736\Gitlab\Inform\e2e\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:2896:21)
>     at asyncRun (C:\Users\gwk736\Gitlab\Inform\e2e\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:2820:25)
>     at C:\Users\gwk736\Gitlab\Inform\e2e\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:639:7
> [12:57:56] E/launcher - Process exited with error code 199
> ```

Anyone encountered this problem when running tests ?
This is a very strange behaviour to me... 
Unfortunately no examples can be found.

Comment: Both the http://www.onet.pl and http://ondemand.saucelabs.com:80/wd/hub are valid URLs and are parsed by `url` node module (used by selenium-webdriver) without any problems. Are you sure you are using this config to run the tests?

Comment: What happens if you run it in directConnect mode and/or locally (not on saucelabs)?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to replicate your error by having incorrectly encoded characters in either `sauceUser` or `sauceKey`. Can you check if you have any such characters in your config?

```
sauceUser: 'myuser',
sauceKey: 'password%EA',
```

Error Stack:

```
[14:41:46] I/sauce - Using SauceLabs selenium server at http://ondemand.saucelabs.com:80/wd/hub
[14:41:46] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
[14:41:46] E/launcher - URI malformed
[14:41:46] E/launcher - URIError: URI malformed
    at decodeURIComponent (native)
    at Url.parse (url.js:195:19)
    at Object.urlParse [as parse] (url.js:84:5)
```

This issue in nodeJs has been explained in this [nodejs git issue](https://github.com/nodejs/node-v0.x-archive/issues/67)

> I just ran into this error when a client encoded 'ê' as '%EA' and an
>   'é' as "%E9" and then sent them to my node server. Attempting to
>   decode either of them result in the uri malformed error:

```
decodeURIComponent("%EA"); URIError: URI malformed at decodeURIComponent (native) at repl:1:1
```